# r bookdown favicon works offline but not online

Tags: r, yaml, r-markdown, bookdown

I build a homepage using [R bookdown by Yihui Xie](https://bookdown.org/). On the documentation page https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/html.html#gitbook-style it is written that a favicon can be added via the YAML metadata by

```
favicon: "favicon.ico"
```

in my [index.Rmd](https://github.com/chrisdane/chrisdane.github.io/blob/0767392ae3a4e770333018d6db3aa5ad70d3f6b9/index.Rmd#L20).

That works offline, but not online: the favicon is not displayed at https://chrisdane.github.io/.

Thanks a lot for any help.
Chris

**Edit**: for whatever reason its working now -_-

Comment: Your favicon file is just a white box? See https://raw.githubusercontent.com/chrisdane/chrisdane.github.io/0767392ae3a4e770333018d6db3aa5ad70d3f6b9/figs/favicon.ico

Comment: No, actually its a picture with a glass of water. Not for you? And to make it clear: no favicon is displayed at all, that means there is no space between the left border and the first letter of the tab title.

Comment: Strange, couldn’t view it in Google’s Chrome browser, but looks ok on Safari browser.